# Calculating Read Time on Astro Blog

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, astrojs

I'm struggling to follow the read time recipe on Astro docs. I have tried to fix this multiple ways but can't seem to find a workaround solution to calculate the time taken to read.

`astro.config.mjs`

```
import { defineConfig } from "astro/config";
import mdx from "@astrojs/mdx";
import sitemap from "@astrojs/sitemap";
import { remarkReadingTime } from "./remark-reading-time";
import react from "@astrojs/react";

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
  site: "https://umma.dev",
  integrations: [mdx(), sitemap(), react()],
  markdown: {
    remarkPlugins: [remarkReadingTime],
    extendDefaultPlugins: true,
  },
});
```

`remark-reading.time.js`

```
import getReadingTime from "reading-time";
import { toString } from "mdast-util-to-string";

/** Estimated Reading time */
export function remarkReadingTime() {
  return function (tree, { data }) {
    const textOnPage = toString(tree);
    const readingTime = getReadingTime(textOnPage);
    data.astro.frontmatter.estReadingTime = readingTime.minutes;
  };
}
```

`BlogPost.astro`

```
---
import type { CollectionEntry } from "astro:content";
import BaseHead from "../components/BaseHead.astro";
import Header from "../components/Header.astro";
import Footer from "../components/Footer.astro";
import FormattedDate from "../components/FormattedDate.astro";

type Props = CollectionEntry<"blog">["data"];

const {
  title,
  description,
  date,
  updatedDate,
  heroImage,
  categories,
  frontmatter,
} = Astro.props;
---

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <BaseHead title={title} description={description} />
    <style>
      .title {
        font-size: 2em;
        margin: 0.25em 0 0;
      }
      hr {
        border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
        margin: 1rem 0;
      }
      .last-updated-on {
        font-style: italic;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <Header />
    <main>
      <article>
        {heroImage && <img width={720} height={360} src={heroImage} alt="" />}
        <h1 class="title">{title}</h1>
        <FormattedDate date={date} />
        {
          updatedDate && (
            <div class="last-updated-on">
              Last updated on <FormattedDate date={updatedDate} />
            </div>
          )
        }
        {categories}
        {frontmatter?.estReadingTime}
        <hr />
        <slot />
      </article>
    </main>
    <Footer />
  </body>
</html>
```

Types are as follows:

```
import { defineCollection, z } from "astro:content";

const FrontmatterSchema = z.object({
  estReadingTime: z.any(),
});

const blog = defineCollection({
  schema: z.object({
    title: z.string(),
    // Transform string to Date object
    date: z
      .string()
      .or(z.date())
      .transform((val) => new Date(val)),
    updatedDate: z
      .string()
      .optional()
      .transform((str) => (str ? new Date(str) : undefined)),
    heroImage: z.string().optional(),
    categories: z
      .enum([
        "Front End",
        "Back End",
      ])
      .optional(),
    notFound: z.string().optional(),
    draft: z.boolean().optional(),
    frontmatter: FrontmatterSchema.optional(),
  }),
});

export const collections = { blog };
```

I can't seem to understand why this doesn't work? Is it because I'm using collections? Could anyone help with understanding why `estReadingTime` is coming back as undefined?

Is there an easier way to do this in Astro rather than using the recipe or this specific plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [content collections](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/content-collections/), frontmatter provided by remark plugins is available from the return value of `.render()` on a collection entry.

```
---
const entry = getEntry(...);
const { Content, remarkPluginFrontmatter } = await entry.render();
console.log(remarkPluginFrontmatter.estReadingTime)
---
```